# Applications shown as "Unknown" on Debian 10/Gnome 3.30.2

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, application-launch, dash

When launching application, some of them show up as "unknown", both in the dock and in the top bar. This persists regardless if they are launched from dash or through a terminal.
If launched from the favourites shortcut, they will pop a new icon in named Unknown.

This is not limited to apps installed from .deb packages, some store apps (e.g. slack) behave the same way.

This was not the case on Ubuntu 19.04, where I also used Gnome as my DE.

The .desktop files all have either a generic `Name=` assigned, or more commonly `Name=` with multiple locales.

What could be causing this? Is this a problem on the applications' side, or is something with debian/gnome?

[image: Dash]
[image: Top Bar]
[image: Duplicate]

Comment: look for such a `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications/` or `/usr/share/applications`, open with a text editor and see if there is `Name=` assigned

Comment: @Andra `Name=` is assigned in every application I have checked

Comment: and Name with your locale - for example, `Name[en_GB]=`. Compare a good .desktop file and that showing "unknown".

Comment: Done that before; vivaldi (the one in my example) has pretty much every locale assigned on top of the generic `Name=`, and editing slack.desktop to match a working one made no difference.